# codeigniter dynamic number of fields inserting

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and doing some insert and update operation on my table from the associative array (which comes from the external website) , where the number of fields are not always same.

Here is my code.

```
 $url ="http://api.peerindex.net/1/profile/show.json?id=$twittername&api_key=xxxxxx";

            $ch = curl_init();  
            $timeout = 5;  
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);  
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);  
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);  
            $peerdata = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            if (strlen($peerdata)>10)
            {
                $peerdata = json_decode($peerdata);
                $this->db->where ("userid", $this->userinfo->userid);
                $this->db->update('userpeerdata', $peerdata);
               }
```

My Table userpeerdata contains around 6 columns but some columns are not exist. What I want is it should take only those columns which are present in database, other should ignore. How can I do this in simple.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Codeigniter's array helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/array_helper.html). They have a nice little function called `elements()`, which will extract only the elements you want:

```
$this->load->helper('array');
$peerdata = json_decode($peerdata);
// Include a list of all your columns in the table...
$peerdata = elements(array('name', 'twitter', 'known', 'authority'), $peerdata);

$this->db->where ("userid", $this->userinfo->userid);
$this->db->update('userpeerdata', $peerdata);
```